# If UIImage not load from url

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

How can i add local image.png to cell if image not load from url?

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    DetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * imagedata,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imagedata];
                                   cell.flowerImage.image = image;
                               }                     
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

`arrayOfImages` - array of url strings that i've parsed from json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the image against nil to verify the image url.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                           NSData * imagedata,
                                           NSError * error) {
                           if (!error){
                               UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imagedata];
                               if(!image) {
                                  cell.flowerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"localImage"]; //local bundle image.
                               } else
                                   cell.flowerImage.image = image;
                           } else {
                               cell.flowerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"localImage"];//local bundle image.
                           }
}];
```

Comment: Check the url that you are using on the browser and check whether there exists an image. You might even get a very small image (say of size 1px square), so verify that in using your browser.